# Put extra error when sending image chunks array?

Tags: java, android, image, split

I want to divide an image into 16 parts and display it in a GridView.
But I get an error when sending image chunks array.
Error is "E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"

What is the solution of this error???

ImageParse.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageParse extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_split;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_parse);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        btn_split = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_split);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_split_image);

        btn_split.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                splitImage(image, 16);
            }
        });
    }

    private void splitImage(ImageView image, int chunkNumbers)
    {

        int rows, cols;

        int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;

        ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages = new ArrayList<>(chunkNumbers);

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
        rows = 4;
        cols = 4;
        chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight() / rows;
        chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / cols;

        int yCoord = 0;
        for(int x=0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            int xCoord = 0;
            for(int y=0; y < cols; y++)
            {
                chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
                xCoord += chunkWidth;
            }
            yCoord += chunkHeight;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(ImageParse.this, ImageChunksActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(this, "FLG1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent.putExtra("image_chunks", chunkedImages);

        startActivity(intent);



    }

}
```

ImageChunksActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.navigationmenu.ListViewAdapter.ImageAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageChunksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_chunks);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image_chunks");

        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridImages);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageChunks));
        grid.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(imageChunks.size()));

    }

}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks;
    private int imageWidth;
    private int imageHeight;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.imageChunks = images;
        this.imageWidth = ((Bitmap)images.get(0)).getWidth();
        this.imageHeight = ((Bitmap)images.get(0)).getHeight();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.imageChunks.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.imageChunks.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long)position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView image;
        if(convertView == null) {
            image = new ImageView(this.mContext);
            image.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(this.imageWidth - 10, this.imageHeight));
            image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            image = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        image.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)this.imageChunks.get(position));
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: store those bitmaps somewhere use the paths and display them i gridview.

Comment: Should I keep the chunks in device memory after I split it up?

Comment: anywhere you like. but sending bitmaps via putextra is not right. There is also a limit of how much data you can send although i am not sure of the precise number

Comment: Okay I got it. But how do I keep the device in memory? Can you help me with this?

Comment: you can see the below answer. you can display the grids in the same activity using fragments. and you can search posts on stackvoerflow. you should be able to find a post that will help you

Comment: Thank you. I think I found out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get an error when sending image chunks array. Error is "E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"

Your `Intent` is too large. It needs to be < 1MB, and in practice should be a lot smaller than that.

> What is the solution of this error?

Possibilities include:

- Merging these into a single activity, using fragments or other techniques to switch the UI within that activity, so that you do not need to try to pass large data between activities
- Caching the bitmaps in a singleton cache manager, bearing in mind that this is an intentional memory leak and as such needs to be implemented *very carefully*

Comment: Thank you. I think I found out how to solve the problem.